# How to manipulate index value in *ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ngfor

I am currently using Angular 6 and i ran into a small doubt.
How can we manipulate the index variable that we get in the *ngFor according to our needs. For example,

```
<li *ngFor="let iah of jsonObj; let i = index;">
   <span>{{jsonObj[i].content}}</span>
   <span>{{jsonObj[(i+1)].content}}</span>
</li>
```

The above snippet will fetch the same object twice and display its content. How is it possible to display i'th object in the first span and (i+1)th object in the second span? Now the way i did it works only for the first iteration. as soon as it moves to the second iteration, repetition will occur. Any ideas about this?

Comment: Can you please tell us what output you want?

Comment: The current output is something like obj1 obj2 in one line then obj2 obj3 in another line and so on...however what I want is something like obj1 obj2 in one line then obj3 obj4 in another line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index variable can't be manipulated in angular. You can place an `ngIf*` condition before your `span div's` to change the view. 
Following is the change in your snippet for reference:

```
<div *ngFor="let iah of jsonObj; let i = index;">
    <li *ngIf="i%2==0">
        <span>{{jsonObj[i].content}}</span>
        <span>{{jsonObj[(i+1)].content}}</span>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, if you want output like this :

```
 - test1 test2
 - test2 test3
 - test3 test4
 - test4
```

then you need to check if your `json[i+1]` has data or not, because after the last index if you use `i+1` the array does not have `i+1` value, so it gives you an error.

So you can use it like this in your html:

```
<li *ngFor="let iah of jsonObj; let i=index;">
    <span> {{ jsonObj[i].content }}</span>
    <span *ngIf="i < jsonObj.length -1"> {{ jsonObj[i+1].content }} </span>
</li>
```

**OR** If you want output like this :

```
- test1 test2
- test3 test4
```

Than you can use below method:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item let-i="index" [ngForOf]="jsonObj">
    <li *ngIf="i%2 == 0">
        <span> {{ jsonObj[i].content }}</span>
        <span *ngIf="i < jsonObj.length -1"> {{ jsonObj[i+1].content }} </span>
    </li>
</ng-template>
```

Check [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2pff1v) Live Demo

Comment: Yes, that seems like a viable solution to me. Thanks! So it means there is no way to manipulate the index provided by angular :(

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to display it column wise from HTML only.

Modify your array by iterating it. You can do it where you are assigning data in it as:

**TS**

```
newJsonObj = [];

for(let i = 0; i<this.jsonObj.length; i++) {
    this.newJsonObj.push({key: this.jsonObj[i].content, value: this.jsonObj[i+1].content})
    i++;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li *ngFor="let iah of newJsonObj;">
   <span>{{iah.key}} </span>
   <span>{{iah.value}}</span>
</li>
```

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/split-array) you can find stackblitz

Comment: Well no doubt this will work but I was trying not to put up extra LOC in the component just to handle the iteration here . Better solution would be to somehow manage the HTML like the others recommended. However, thank you very much for your POV too :)

Answer (score -1):

your index is -1 behind what you really want. This means at the first iteration you print out

```
index = 0;
jsonObj[0].content
jsonObj[1].content

index= 1;
jsonObj[1].content
jsonObj[2].content

index=2:
jsonObj[2].content
jsonObj[3].content
```

Comment: The above solutions suffice my requirement ! And yes you are right, this is the current scenario happening with me and I want it to be in a sequential manner like value 0 and 1 in one row then 2 and 3 in another and so on. Thanks for your contribution . I love the stack community :)